# Javascript: Scope of a Variable across different Javascript files

Tags: javascript, scope

I defined a variable in one of my JavaScript files. I want to access the value of that variable among JavaScript files. In one file I am initializing the value of that variable.

I cannot access the assigned value in another JS files.

Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: can you show us how you declared it? and where exactly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to access them if they are in the global scope or can be accessed from the global scope.

For example, I have a object literal like this in my HTML in a `script` element...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
       basePath: '/path/'
    };
</script>
```

Which I can access in any other subsequent JavaScript file with `config.basePath`.

Comment: Can this be in a separate js file?  I have tried this, and I cannot seem to get it working. I get,  Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined

Comment: @diek You will need to research JS scoping, but yes it's possible to be a in a different file.

Comment: hey alex, thanks I actually went with a different approach. But I did get yours to work as well.

Answer (score 9):

It has to be a global variable, or accessible in the same scope (e.g. a property on something else that's global), and it has to be defined *before* you're accessing it, meaning the order of your script includes matters.

You can't for instance have this in one file:

```
(function() {
   var something = "blah";
})();
```

...and access it in the next file, since that variable is scoped to that function.

Answer (score 6):

also, once globally defined, you might need to be accessing it via the window object like this: window.your_variable OR window['your_variable']