# Javascript functions, accessing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   listofLOBs: function(data) { //passing data 
        var returnLOB = [];
        console.log(data);
        for (var i1r= 0; i1r < data.length; i1r++) {
                var lob = new LOBslist();
                lob.name = data[i1r].name;
                lob.id = data[i1r].id;
                returnLOB.push(lob); // storing in returnLOB
            }
        console.log(returnLOB[1].name); 
        $('#mainWrapper').find('select[name="lob-select"] option:selected').text(returnLOB[1].id); //using the returnLOB's object data to populate dropdown
        return returnLOB; 
    }
```

In the above function i am storing objects in the returnLOB array and using it inside the function itself to populate a dropdown.

But say this is file1.js, i would like to access returnLOB's values from file2.js How can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Note: i have declared returnLOB[] globally too.(outside the above function)

Comment: Include them in the same file and call the function

Comment: What's problem exactly ? If you include 2.js after 1.js, you should be able to access that variable.

Comment: Sorry Maybe i didnt put it right, the question is how to call the variable from file 2? thanks

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, you just need to remove `var` from your function so that you're not creating a local variable that shadows the global variable you've created in another file.

```
listofLOBs: function(data) {
    // Here you're setting a global instead of a local
    returnLOB = [];
```

You probably know this is a bad idea, and it would be better if you restructure your code so that you don't need a global

A simple solution is to have all code that needs the variable in one place with a self-executing function so your global is only exposed to the code that needs it

```
(function(){
    var returnLob;

    ... contents of file 1, which write to returnLob

    ... contents of file 1, which read returnLob

})()
```

Comment: sorry may be i didnt put my question correct, Say i want to use returnLOB in file 2, how cna i do that? How do i use returnLOB's values? Do i need to call listofLOBs() function? Please help.

Comment: If you can call `var list = obj.listofLOBs()` from the second file, that is your best choice. That means you must have instantiated your object that has a method `listofLobs()` into the `obj` variable

Answer (score 0):

As long as you include `file1.js` **before** `file2.js`, it will work. Take jQuery as an example - or any JS library for that matter - if you include its source file before your code, you can use functions within it.

You want to include the files in the above order, then you can just call the function (`listofLOBs()`) in file 2.

Additionally, your variable declaration within the function is incorrect.

```
var returnLOB = [];     // You're declaring a global.
```

should be

```
returnLOB = [];      // because the variable is already declared - you just want a local copy.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access any globals between files. In your example you defined returnLOB inside of a function so that won't be accessible but the one you claimed to have defined globally will be accessible by both files.

This also has been asked before so check out:

[Javascript: Scope of a Variable across different Javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022606/javascript-scope-of-a-variable-across-different-javascript-files)

Comment: It won't work, the OP is creating a local variable which is shadowing the global

Comment: Well ya that's a given, if you name a local variable by the same name then the global is no longer accessible. I figured the poster knew that because the easy solution is to name the local variable differently.